# How do you custom arragement of a dictionary by key in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
 { "country", "1" },
 { "state", "2" },
 { "name", "3" },
 { "type", "4" }
};
```

I want to arrage the dictionary elements  in a specific order shown below

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
  { "name", "3" },
  { "type", "4" },
  { "country", "1" },
  { "state", "2" }
};
```

Is it possible for dictionary type? I would appreciate it if you give a solution for that

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Look up the `OrderedDictionary` class.

Comment: custome arrangement is not psossible as per my knowledge

Comment: @Rob - that order according to its algo ...so its not supporting custom ordering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't rely on the order in a `Dictionary`. It's implementation-specific, and can change in unexpected ways.

In this case, it sounds like *really* you should have a custom type instead, with `Country`, `State`, `Name` and `Type` properties.

An alternative would be to have a separate list of well-known keys in the order you want - you can always iterate over *that* and fetch the appropriate key:

```
foreach (var key in keysInOrder)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, dictionary[key]);
}
```

If you really *really* want an `IDictionary<,>` in a particular order, you could always implement it yourself, maintaining a key order as a list *and* a `Dictionary<,>` internally. But this feels like a design smell, to be honest.